# Changing colors of a Python for-loop in Vim

Tags: python, vim, colors

I've just started learning python and I'm using MacVim as my editor with the Jellybeans color scheme. When I write a for-loop in python the 'for' is colored blue(ish) while the 'in' is not. I see in other themes they are both colored the same. How do I edit the jellybeans theme to get that?

Here's a picture showing what I mean:
[image: picture showing <code>in</code> not highlighted]

Comment: Don't know. I've always used 'dark' color scheme in macvim. Tried installing some other scheme but seemed complicated.

Comment: This user has made his own color scheme. If you really want to use 'jellybeans' then why not look in to what he has done. _Have no idea what so ever if this helps though._ https://github.com/mitsuhiko/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/colors/fruity.vim **ELSE, suggestion. Use a different color scheme.**

Comment: The "scheme" tag refers to the Scheme programming language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29

Comment: Not a programming question, belong to superuser.com

Comment: @e-satis: vim/emacs questions that specifically have to do with using the editors for programming have a fairly good consensus as on-topic here. (hell, vim/emacs questions that have nothing to do with programming at all also have a slightly less strong consensus, although I vote to migrate those ones myself)

Comment: @e-satis - Please knock it off with vim+offtopic ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su unless you have a very strong reason for objecting.

Comment: Dura lex sed lex. Still stupid lex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim's python syntax file [defines](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/syntax/python.vim?r=d0049ff596#80) `in` as part of the `pythonOperator` syntax group. The `pythonOperator` group is [linked to](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/syntax/python.vim?r=d0049ff596#268) the built-in `Operator` group, which is (by default) linked in turn to `Statement`.

Jellybeans instead [links](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/blob/2c306097f8320286ae26fd9e45b9c0a8911ec210/colors/jellybeans.vim#L347) `Operator` to `Normal` to get uncolored symbolic operators (`+`, `*`, etc) without changing `Statement`.

Adding a special case link directly from `pythonOperator` to `Statement` restores the coloring.

---

tl;dr [I fixed it](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/commit/2c306097f8320286ae26fd9e45b9c0a8911ec210). Grab a new copy from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to *"accomplish"* that. Could you give the link from where you downloaded the aforementioend *Jellybeans* color scheme?

My first look would be whether in the colorscheme there is something that overwrites the *"in"* element into a different color than the *"for"* element. If there is nothing inside, then it must be something with the syntax highlighting for python.

But in that case, that would also show with other color schemes as well.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the loops in only python, add this to your .vimrc after you set the color-scheme

```
autocmd FileType python hi Repeat guifg=#hexnumber
```

with #hexnumber the gui code for the color you want to change the color of just the operators replace Repeat with operator

edit:

I might have misunderstood your question loops are in the highlight group repeat and in is in the hi-group operator both belong to the group statement so if statement is the only one set in you color-scheme you have to set Repeat and operator yourself